# Wpf C# Change checkBox comboboxitem color + disable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list which is populated with a .distinct from other list, then I get these items and create checkboxes to populate a combobox.

After apllying some filter I have to search for these combobox items in a the second list and if it doesn´t exist I have to disable the item and set its background color.

```
// List to populate the combobox
public List<System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox> ListaCmbMnMe { get; set; }

//...

ListaCmbMnMe = new List<System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox>();

// ListaPendencia is populated from database MnMe is a column from it
foreach (string item in ListaPendencia.Select(p => p.MnMe).Distinct())
{
    checkBox = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
    checkBox.Content = item;

    ListaCmbMnMe.Add(checkBox);
}

//...
// Just trying to change the properties to find out if it works
foreach (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox item in ListaCmbMnMe)
{
    item.IsEnabled = false;
    item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(102, 153, 255));
}

cmbMnMe.ItemsSource = ListaCmbMnMe;
```

I´m doing nothing special on xaml.

Neither the color is changed nor the disable works.

Comment: Are you assigning to ItemsSource after the loop, as it appears in the question?

Comment: Also, if you put a breakpoint in the loop, does it hit the breakpoint in the debugger?

Comment: Show your xaml. I am guessing you haven't added CheckBoxes into the visual tree. You added collection to ItemsSource which is supposed to be DataSource collection and not a UI element collection.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

I voted your comments as usefull whereas it makes me remember that I was not binding the "IsEnabled" property on xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply had forgotten to bind the "IsEnabled" property on xaml.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding to `cmbMnMe.ItemsSource = ListaCmbMnMe;` which is meant for datasource; i.e. datacontext; add it to `Items`. No need to have another list collection of checkboxes.

```
// ListaPendencia is populated from database MnMe is a column from it
foreach (string item in ListaPendencia.Select(p => p.MnMe).Distinct())
{
    checkBox = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
    checkBox.Content = item;

    checkBox.IsEnabled = false;
    checkBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(102, 153, 255));

    cmbMnMe.Items.Add(checkBox);    
}
```

Ideally you should be using data binding using a DataTemplate that has a checkbox and necessary binding; using MVVM pattern.

Comment: I voted your comment as usefull whereas it makes me remember that I was not binding the "IsEnabled" property on xaml.